# Angular2, constructor DI throws exception

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I just started with Angular2. I have read all tutors on Angular2 website and started working on my project and got stuck right after.

Here are sources.

app.ts:

```
import { Component }            from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap }            from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ApiClient }            from './services/api-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: 'Hello',
  providers: [ApiClient]
})
export class AppComponent { constructor(private apiClient: ApiClient) { } }

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

api-client.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class ApiClient {
    public login(username: string, password: string, rememberMe: boolean) : boolean {
    if (username == 'testuser' && password == 'password')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

And this simple source code gives me a very strange exception:
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: dep is null

If I remove constructor DI then exception gone.

I have been struggling with it for last 4 hours and have no any ideas for to fix it. Another strange thing is that exception message is useless.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

By constructor DI I mentioned this:

```
constructor(private apiClient: ApiClient) { }
```

**Update 2**

I have replaced Injectable() with Component({}) and now it works perfect. What does it mean? Broken local Angular2 sources or some kind of misconfiguration?

Comment: I posted some explanation about why this can't work. What I'm missing in your question is what you expect to happen. Angular DI can't create a `password`, `username` and `rememberMe` from thin air ;-). Where do you want or expect them to come from?

Comment: I have removed this method and still getting this exception

Comment: public login(username: string, password: string, rememberMe: boolean)

Comment: Ouch, I didn't look properly. Sorry, I thought this is a constructor. There is no need to remove this method.

Comment: Where is the constructor from that you added by your update? Is it the one from `AppComponent` you have in your first code snippet already?

Comment: export class AppComponent { constructor(private apiClient: ApiClient) { } }

Comment: I can't reproduce https://plnkr.co/edit/ccQFWcQTVAX3oWKSsDih?p=preview

Comment: That's confusing. Now you have the same constructor twice in your question.

Comment: If you already checked the plunker, I updated it because I forgot the constructor :-/ but it's still working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!!!

For some reason "node_modules\es6-shim" was missing!

I have no any idea why Firefox was not notifying me about that.
Started web app in Chrome and noticed warning about missing JS reference.

Executed "npm install es6-shim" and now it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

...
    export class AppComponent { 

         constructor(@Inject(ApiClient) apiClient: ApiClient) { } 
    }
```

Could be worth you showing the constructor of your ApiClient class if you have one.

Comment: If this `@Inject()` is necessary then there is probably something else wrong in your code. If the type passed to `@Inject()` is the same as the type of the parameter itself `@Inject()` is redundant.

Comment: Inject helped. Thanks. However I guess that this is kinda workaround rather than proper fix

Comment: I have replaced Injectable() with Component({}) and now it works perfect. What does it mean? Broken local Angular2 sources or some kind of misconfiguration?